# Sort ListView by Colum

Tags: c#, sorting, listview, gridview

I find out this code:

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Is there anything like this but for listView in C#?

**Edit:** I have a listView like this.[image: ListView]

How can I sort lvi by Name or Last Name? I find out this but sort the lvi by Id.

```
listView_Test.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
// or
listView_Test.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
```

Comment: Which listview are you talking about? Regardless, you might just want to sort the data instead of manipulating UI elements.

Comment: Perhaps this helps [Is it possible to bind a List to a ListView in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799017/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-list-to-a-listview-in-winforms)

Comment: @Crowcoder I edit my topic so maybe now it is more clear